# Accessing next previous row while rendering Angular Material table

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-material-table

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="weight">
  <th cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
  <td cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

I want to display {{element.weight} + element of previous row.weight} like a rolling weight total. What is the syntax? Working sample source is taken from 
[here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/table/overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented the Rolling weight total by custom logic, Please go through and comment if you have any doubts!

[image: Result]

[Stack blitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cmbtpb-owrp22?file=app%2Fcdk-table-basic-example.ts)

In html

```
    <!-- Weight Column -->
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="weight">
    <th cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let element"> {{getElementWeight(element)}} </td>
    <!--  <td cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td> -->
</ng-container>
```

---

In ts

```
declare global {
interface Array < T > {
    getSummedWeight(): any;
    containsElement(e: any): any;
     }
  }

    custom:any = [];
getElementWeight(e) {
    if (this.custom.containsElement(e)) {
        this.custom = [];
        console.log("########contains#####")
    }
    this.custom.push({
        'position': e.position,
        'name': e.name,
        'weight': e.weight,
        'newweight': e.weight + (this.custom.length == 0 ? 0 : this.custom.getSummedWeight())
    })
    console.log(this.custom)
    return this.custom.length == 0 ? 0 : this.custom[this.custom.length - 1].newweight

}


  if (!Array.prototype.getSummedWeight) {
Array.prototype.getSummedWeight = function(): any {
    let totalWeight = this.length == 1 ? this[this.length - 1].weight :
        this[this.length - 1].weight;
    return totalWeight;
    }
}
  if (!Array.prototype.containsElement) {
Array.prototype.containsElement = function(e): any {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i].position === e.position)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: your stackblitz link is broken. Can you please repost so I can fork and save. Thanks